# Interval of 1 second not working in input.conf

Tags: input, splunk

I want to run my script at every second, so I set interval to 1 second in input.conf file. But the script is not executed every second. So is there any minimum interval amount? Following is my input.conf file:

```
[amqp]
index = default
start_by_shell = false
sourcetype = amqp
interval = 1
reconnect = True
ssl_enabled = False

[amqp://input01]
interval = 1
reconnect = 1
source_url = 10.0.1.11:33037/examples
ssl_enabled = 0
```

Comment: Does the script not execute at all, or does it execute at a different interval than 1 second? If so, what is the interval?

Comment: It executes at some random intervals

Comment: how long does the script take to run? iirc, the UF won't start it again if it's still running